# How can we get specific links using simple html dom

Tags: php, mysql, simple-html-dom

I have used this script which i found in the official simple html dom site to find hyperlinks in a website

```
foreach($html->find('a') as $element) 
       echo $element->href . '<br>';
```

it returned all the links found in the website but i want only specific links in that website.
is there a way of doing it in simple html dom. This is the html code for that specific links

```
<a class="z" href="http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-middle-east-16893609" target="_blank" rel="follow">middle east</a>
```

where this is the html tag which is different from other hyperlinks

> `<a class="z"`

and also there is any way i can get the link text ("middle east") together with the link.

Comment: do you want to use javascript dom or php?

Comment: if z class includes only your specific links just use $html->find('.z') instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand you'd like all `a` elements with the class `z`? You can do that like this:

```
foreach($html->find('a.z') as $element)
```

You can get an element's value (which for links will be the link text) with the `plaintext` property:

```
$element->plaintext
```

Please note that this can all be found in [the manual](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm).