# How to validate plain text (link text)  in a hyperlink using php?

Tags: php

I am using simple html dom to fetch datas from other websites. while fetching data it fetches both hyperlinks with plain text and without plain text. I want to remove hyperlinks without plain text(link text) while fetching the data ..
i have tried below codes

```
if($title==""){ echo "No text";}
```

and

```
if(ctype_space($title)) { echo "No text";}
```

where $title is the plaintext fetched from the website

but both method didnt worked..can any one help

Advance thanks for your help

Comment: Can you give examples of what `$title` might be? I don't understand what you mean by plain text.

Comment: coud you pleas make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: sorry for that, in a link like this <a href="url">Link text</a> where "url" is the web address and  "Link text" is the plain text

Comment: @Neysor, how would a jsfiddle help when this is php?

Comment: @test, I still not sure what you mean. Can you fill in these blanks, `$title_plaintext = ...` and `$title_notplaintext = ...`

Comment: you can see the twitter link below this page ...twitter is the plaintext and this is its hyperlink (http://twitter.com/share?url=http%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2fq%2f9544760%2f996366%3fstw%3d2&text=How%20to%20validate%20plain%20text%20in%20a%20hyperlink%20using%20php%3f)

Comment: if you go to this link you will understand what i meant plain text http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9518368/how-can-we-get-specific-links-using-simple-html-dom/9518469#9518469

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko sry you're right! Thought about equal pages, but doesn't matter...

Comment: What is the value of `$title` when there is no text? Try something like this `echo "'" . $title ."'"` and let us know the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until you give us more information on what value is my best guess would be to try something like this

```
if(empty($title))
{
    echo "No Text";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Does it really need to be "plain text validation"?

Reading your question it seems you just want to remove links with empty values.

If the latter is true, you can do something like this:

```
$html = <<<EOL
<a href="#">Text</a>
<a href="#"></a>
<a href="#">More Text</a>
<a href="#"></a>
EOL;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

foreach ($links as $link) {
    if (strlen(trim($link->nodeValue)) == 0) {
        $link->parentNode->removeChild($link);
    }
}

var_dump($dom->saveHTML());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xPath = new DOMXPath($html);

$links_array = $xPath->query("//a"); // select all a tags

$totalLinks = $links_array->length; // how many links there are.

for($i = 0; $i < $totalLinks; $i++) // process each link one by one
{
   $title = $links_array->item($i)->nodeValue; // get LInkText
   if($title == '') // if no link text
   {

      $url = $links_array->item($i)->getAttribute('href');
      // do here what you want 
    }

}
```

Answer (score -3):

You need to use preg_match, with a regular expression, to extract the link text.  For example

```
if (preg_match("/<a.*?>(.*?)</",$title,$matches))
{
   echo $matches[1];
}
```

Comment: using simple html dom we can extract the link text http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9518368/how-can-we-get-specific-links-using-simple-html-dom/9518469#9518469 . what i want is that i have to validate whether there is a text or not

Comment: it's easier and faster to use regexps that to create a DOM object and manipulate it

Comment: Regex is only going to work when you know the stucture of the data. It's common for HTML to be invalid and therefore Regex should not be used to parse it.